# File .../src/preact.d.ts' is not a module.ts(2306)

Tags: typescript, vite, preact

I am trying to cope with typescript issue.

```
File '/src/preact.d.ts' is not a module.ts(2306)
```

preact.d.ts

```
import JSX = preact.JSX
```

The error occurred in:

```
import { createContext } from 'preact'
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using Preact's types, but trying to define your own?

Comment: This is default configuration created by Vite.js.

Comment: Ah, alright, forgot they were doing that. It looks like this is a case of a configured editor, as I cannot replicate it. Have you edited your `tsconfig.json` at all? https://vite.new/preact-ts doesn't show any errors, so this looks like it's localized to your setup.

Comment: Have you any idea where I should look? I thought that I did all good. I will be grateful for any tips! Thank you!